# Why isn't my CSS rule being applied as expected?

Tags: html, css

I have many different CSS files. I define a class in the common CSS like this:

**common.css**

```
.container-example {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.container-example > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It works in all my HTML files.

However, in one HTML file, for one div I need the `overflow-y: auto;`. Therefore I create a specific class in another CSS file:

**other.css**

```
.override-overflow {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-example">
  <div class="override-overflow">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work in my div because it take in account the overflow:hidden.
It works if I add `overflow-y=auto !important;` but I would like to avoid it.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about specificity. .container-example > div is worth more than an individual class. In the specified file, or in your main CSS file, you will have to overwrite that with a value that's worth more. For example,

```
.container-example > div.override-overflow {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

is worth more than

```
.container-example > div {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check [CSS-Trick Guide](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

That is because it is being overwritten by

```
.container-example > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change it to:

```
.container-example > div:not(.override-overflow) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/not/) for more information about the `:not()` selector.